# Can you miss the chance to achieve 100%?

Tags: days-gone

So yesterday I had a quest (a white rather than a yellow marker) that was leading me again to Sarahs tombstone. I think it was called "I shouldn't have come here" or something like that. I continued a few main story missions and ended up at Lost Lake. When I by then considered heading back to make that mentioned quest, the marker was gone.

So now I am wondering, is that quest just temporarily gone?
Or should I always head to none main quests first as I otherwise will miss the chance to achieve 100%? Or is there another way to avoid missing quests if this is the case?

Comment: Please consider editing the question - you have two very different questions here: Can you miss 100% completion, and what happened to the white quest marker. You should commit to only one of those questions.

Comment: @PausePause: I disagree, as the question in the title will be successional answered by giving an answer to the question in the body. Either "There is no way to finish missions that became unfinished unavailable at one point." What would lead the title to be answered with "yes", or the answer would be a workaround / info about how/when you can still finish them which automatically would answer the other question with "no". So I don't think this is that problematic here.